# How to add Get Started button in the typing bar using bot builder sdk for node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, facebook-messenger

I am using bot builder sdk for node.js to create a chatbot. Also connected it to facebook channel. I am using the following code to greet the user:

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
    (session, result, next) => {

        let text = '';
        switch(session.message.address.channelId) {
            case 'facebook':
                text = 'Hi ' + session.message.user.name + ' !';
                break;    
            default:
                text = 'Hi !';
        }        

        session.sendTyping();
        session.say(text);
        next();
    },
    (session, say) => {
    }
]);
```

The above code works fine, but I want to add "Get Started" button in the typing bar to invoke the above code. Note that this button appears only once. Please find image of the typing bar below:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this using bot builder sdk for node.js ?

Thanks

Comment: When you say you want to add a button, do you mean in the actual text input section (where it says 'Type a message') or in the chat box above it?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes I can see that the typing bar in the image has 6 buttons docked on the right. I presume that is where the button is meant to go.

Comment: @AshyAshcsi The buttons available in any given typing bar tend to be specific to the website, application, etc. that you are chatting in, and are therefore largely outside the scope of the Bot Framework. Customizing the buttons would have to be a feature of the service that's hosting the chat system. I think the best way to do what you're thinking of doing is to have the bot display a Get Started button in one of its initial messages, and perhaps when the user asks for help. Or if you really want to have control over the buttons in the typing bar, you might consider making your own website.

Comment: @AshyAshcsi I presume your screenshot is taken from Facebook. I haven't found any way to customize chat buttons in Facebook, and if I can't do it as a normal user then I wouldn't expect to be able to have a bot do it. Remember that a bot is mostly just there to talk the way a normal user would, and it doesn't have significant control over its environment. As a normal user, consider whether you'd expect to be able to reach through the chat window and affect the environment settings on the other user's machine! (cont.)

Comment: @AshyAshcsi In that light, we can think of a bot as being on a different machine with little to no control over the machine of the person it's talking to. So even if a user is able to change the buttons that show up in their typing bar, a bot probably can't make those kinds of changes to the user's environment. However, a bot can send messages that contain buttons. I'm writing these as comments rather than an answer because I want to wait to see if you decide that that's an acceptable alternative to putting a button in the typing bar.

Comment: @KyleDelaney, I want the button to appear in the typing bar. I have seen it for other messenger chatbots. If not I want to display message and Get Started button, even before the session is started. Something like below:
builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Welcome", "Get Started");
I asked because I have seen the button appear for few other chatbots.
Thanks

Comment: @AshyAshcsi That's very interesting. For the sake of my own research, do you happen to have a link to a page where I can observe this extra button in the typing bar?

Answer (score 1):

Although one can certainly add a button to start any activity with the bot, but that will limit the bots potential to only one customizable channel, i.e. WebChat.

I think there are better 2 alternative ways to get the desired functionality which will work across many channels.

**First**

I would suggest to add a `conversation update` event. Code goes in the `botbuilder's` middleware. Here is a sample code from the docs.

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
if (message.membersAdded && message.membersAdded.length > 0) {
    // Say hello
    var txt = "Send me a Hi";
    var reply = new builder.Message()
            .address(message.address)
            .text(txt);
    bot.send(reply);
});
```

What this will do is make the bot send a message *Send me a Hi* to the user, if it determines this is a first time visitor. This will give the visitor enough cue to send the bot *Hi* by typing it. Although he can enter whatever he wants, but this will result in the invocation of the 1st dialog configured which in this case is the will be the dialog which you have posted in question.

**Second**

You can mark some dialog to be invoked automatically if your bot has never encountered this visitor. Here is the sample code...

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
bot.dialog('firstRun', function (session) {    
    session.userData.firstRun = true;
    session.send("Hello...").endDialog();
}).triggerAction({
    onFindAction: function (context, callback) {
        // Only trigger if we've never seen user before
        if (!context.userData.firstRun) {
            // Return a score of 1.1 to ensure the first run dialog wins
            callback(null, 1.1);
        } else {
            callback(null, 0.0);
        }
    }
});
```

Here we have split the bot creation and dialog registration in 2 steps. And while registering the *firstRun* dialog, we have provided it the triggerAction that if the visitor is new, then trigger this dialog.

Both of these approaches do not use adding some extra buttons and it is up to the bot either to educate him on sending some message which in turn will start the 1st dialog or directly start some dialog.

For more info on conversationEvent you can refer to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-handle-conversation-events?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above options, but they didn't seem to be working for facebook messenger. But I found a solution to add the Get Started button into the typing bar of the messenger. For that we need to use the Facebook Graph API and not the bot builder sdk.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>

{ 
  "get_started":{
    "payload":"Get Started"
  }
}
```

The above API call will add the button for you to get the conversation started.

Thanks all for the help!!